# How to get last query performed with MariaSQL Node JS module?

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb

I'm using the [mariasql NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariasql) in Node JS and connecting to a MariaSQL 5.5.60 server.  How can I retrieve the last query that was executed by the current connection?

For example,

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = :name AND city = :city", { name: "John Smith", city: "Poughkeepsie" }, (err, data) => {
    // Log the query that was executed:
    console.log("Executed query was: " + connection.__someFunctionToGetLastQuery___());
    // Should display "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name = 'John Smith' AND city = 'Poughkeepsie'"
});
```

If there's a better/more up-to-date/complete MariaDB module, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: You can query `mysql.general_log` ***IF*** you have enabled the [MariaDB General Query Log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/general-query-log/) which is disabled by default.

Comment: *However... you are using prepared statements here and those don't translate to just straight SELECT statements like that, so you might not be able to get exactly what you want here. With a prepared statement the statement (before the parameters are bound) are sent to the database. The database parses the sql and generates and execution path. It's essentially compiled code at this point. THEN the parameters are bound and the results are pulled back. That's what makes them so secure, and it might foil your plans to get a nice select statement back.

Comment: HAHA I just found this question by searching, didn't even realize I had asked it.  Did a double-take when I saw my name as the author.  :)